# Conditions for running the program

Tags: c#, permissions, exe, user-permissions

I wrote a main program in C#, and I worte also a small tool program also in C#.

I want that the tool program will be able to execute under some conditions:

- When called from my main program.
- When called from open some suffix of file (e.g. "*.abc")

But if the user open my program directory he can run the tool program, and I do not want him to be able to do it. I want him to be able to run the program under the conditions above. And if he ran the program manually, the program automatically shut.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you need to put the whole program under a thread and then LOCK that thread...

Comment: My main program? It very heavy program, I cant do it.

Comment: ok,download the exe from the link and see if it works,as it worked in my case...http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35826/Restricting-application-execution-in-Windows

Comment: It's not exactly what I meant...

Comment: Prevent the user from running the tool manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if your main program called it, you could pass the main program's `ProcessID` as a commandline argument, then in your small program, check if that `ProcessID` exists and if its process name is the name of your main program. This isn't spoof-proof, but might be a bit trickier to fake than just passing a static number/string.

In addition, you could encrypt the number and pass that, then decrypt it and check the above. It's pretty much impossible to prevent a determined hacker from running your program on its own, but you can raise the bar of how tricky it is to do it. You'd also want to obfuscate your code, otherwise a quick Reflector call will show exactly what characters are being passed.

Alternatively, if possible, you could just make the small program a DLL and call it from your main program like that. This would need a bit of refactoring, but would force your program to be open. As for opening a `*.abc` file, your program can check the command line arguments to see if a filename was passed through. This can then be processed automatically by your app and the DLL calls can be made.

Comment: But how is that any more obvious than just passing a flag?

Comment: +1 I loved the idea for make it DLL, I didn't think about it. But I will still use some data for "permission". Any program can be hacked, a hucker can use dll injection to listen the "permission" thet passed. But it enough for my. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing exposed to the process/executing environment that tells it how it was invoked, so there is no foolproof way to do this.

You can have your main program pass in a flag on the command line - this and the suffix are things that you can check for and if either one does not exist you terminate immediately.

However, if the user ever guesses the flag, they can still call the application directly.

Other mechanisms could involve writing a value to a file from your main program just before invoking the second program and checking that file from your second program (and deleting it after execution), as a messaging mechanism. There are other messaging mechanisms that would do similar things (private MSMQ queues for instance).

Comment: Use a hash/guid. Would be harder to "guess".

Comment: @StampedeXV - Security by obscurity.

Comment: no, just harder to guess. If you want security you need to think in different paths.

Comment: So, if I will do it with the file way. That means that I need to do it only if I call to this program from my main program, and if it open by the suffix the command line parameter is enough. Am I right?

Comment: @Someone - Sure, but you need to consider what happens with _multiple_ calls to the application.

Comment: @Someone - What you want to do is not exactly clear.  If you use parameter a user can supply the required parameters by using a shortcut.  You cannot prevent an application from being launched by the user, so don't try to, its not clear the reason you want to prevent it to begin with.

Comment: @Oded - Hmm, I didn't think about that. if my main program create the file and ran the tool program, the user will be able to run it too, cause the file exist. What if I will delete the file when my tool program stat? The user will be able to run the tool in very littel type, but still possible.

Comment: @Ramhound - My main program works with user permissions, I want the tool to be possible only to users with administrator permission. I do not want that everyone that can open the software folder will be able to run the tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [named mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) with some hard-to-guess name to make sure that the "small tool" program was called by the main program. So, you create a Mutex in your parent program:

```
bool requestInitialOwnership = true;
bool mutexWasCreated;
Mutex m = new Mutex(requestInitialOwnership, 
                        "MyMutex", 
                        out mutexWasCreated);
```

Then in your child program you write the exact same code to check if the parent program executed it. If `mutexWasCreated==true`, then it was *not* called by the parent program. Otherwise, it was.
Checking the arguments passed to the program will help to determine whether the filename's extension is `.abs` or not.